# iOS:Passing data to front SWRevealViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiviewcontroller

I have the following viewControllers:[image]
When I click the "Go to gray" it loads the gray viewController using SWRevealViewController.

Here is my code:

```
#import "SWRevealViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (IBAction)gotoGray:(id)sender
{
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    SWRevealViewController *swrController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SWRevealViewController"];
    [self presentViewController:swrController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

My Question to you guys is how can pass data from the blue view controller to the gray (front SWRevealViewController) ?

I'll really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

You have a reference to it with `SWRevealViewController *swrController`, you can set data on the reference by using information from the presenting view controller.

```
- (IBAction)gotoGray:(id)sender
{
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    SWRevealViewController *swrController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SWRevealViewController"];
    swrController.aProperty = self.myInformation;
    swrContoller.anArray = self.arrayOfInfo
    [self presentViewController:swrController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: thank you. But the problem with you suggestion is the property is in the SWRevealViewController and not on gray view controller. SWRevealViewController servers as traffic controller.

Comment: @user2924482 I'm sorry, I was confused by your question, then. What class is the gray view controller? How does the `SWRevealViewController` present the gray view controller? I think we need more information in your question.

Comment: you can take a look to the framework https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController

Comment: Because your framework doesn't require the `frontViewController` to be initialized at the time of the `SWRevealViewController`, and I don't know the details of the example you are working on, it's difficult to be sure, but essentially you need a reference to the `frontViewController` at this point in  order to keep `SWRevealViewController` generic. When you instantiate the `frontViewController` to be added to the `SWRevealViewController` would be the right time, before you call `setFrontViewController`.